# Trying to update an image texture in screenmanager throws index out of range error

Tags: opencv, kivy, kivymd

Im trying to update the texture of an image on a second screen on my application. When I try to do this it throws an Index out of range error.

I think this might be because im not updating this on the main thread as im trying to do it via the second window, but I dont know how I could structure the program any differently, without splitting up the two screens.

Code and Logs and screenshots

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow: 


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "Login"

    MDTextField:
        
        id: ipAddress

        hint_text: "drone ip"

        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None

        height: 30
        width: 200
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}

        on_text_validate: app.ip_validate(ipAddress.text)


    MDSpinner:

        id: spinnerIP

        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(20), dp(20)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .45}
        
        active: False

    MDLabel:

        id: timeLbl

        text: "I am here"
        theme_text_color: "Hint"
        font_size: ipAddress.font_size

        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.52, 'center_y': 0.95}


<MainWindow>

    name: "Main"

    MDLabel:

        id: timeLbl

        text: "I am here"
        theme_text_color: "Hint"

        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.52, 'center_y': 0.95}

    Image:

        id: imageFrame
        
        source: "images/noSignal.jpg"
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
```

```
# adding sub-modules
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

# auxillary libraries
import cv2
import socket
import threading 
import subprocess
import numpy as np 
from enum import Enum
from datetime import datetime

# kivy libraries
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 

# module libraries 
#from Networking.GCSPublisher import GCSPublisher

# Window Enum class
class windows(Enum):
    loginWindow = 0
    mainWindow = 1

# login window class
class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

# main window class
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

# window manager
class WindowManager(ScreenManager): 
    pass


# class - UAVApp
class UAVApp(MDApp):

    # current frame
    currentFrame = windows.loginWindow.name

    # builds the application
    def build(self):
        
        # layout options
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

        # creating capture for imagery
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        # scheduling image clock
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.frame_capture, 1/30.0)

        # scheduling time clock
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.time_function, 1)  

        return Builder.load_file('UAVApp.kv') 


    # a function to capture frames from the receiver
    def frame_capture(self, dt):
        
        if(self.currentFrame == windows.mainWindow.name):

            # get frame
            ret, frame = self.capture.read()

            if(ret):

                bufferFrame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)    
                bufferFrameStr = bufferFrame.tostring()

                imageTexture = Texture.create(size = (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt = 'bgr')
                imageTexture.blit_buffer(bufferFrameStr, colorfmt = 'bgr', bufferfmt = 'ubyte')

                self.root.screens[windows.mainWindow.value].ids['imageFrame'].texture = imageTexture # update texture

    # a function to update the time label
    def time_function(self, dt):

        if(self.currentFrame == windows.loginWindow.name):
            now = datetime.now()

            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            #self.root.ids.timeLbl.text = current_time
            self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.timeLbl.text = current_time # todo: make this an enum 

    # ADC threading
    def controlThread(self, name):
        # opening connection to drone
        gcsPublisher = GCSPublisher(self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.ipAddress.text)

    # on ip text field validation
    def ip_validate(self, text):

        self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.spinnerIP.active = True

        validIP = self.checkIP(self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.ipAddress.text)

        if(not validIP):
            self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.spinnerIP.active = False
            self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.ipAddress.text = ""
            return
        self.root.screens[windows.loginWindow.value].ids.spinnerIP.active = False

        # Create thread for networking and control 
        #try:
        #   t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.controlThread, args=("",))
        #   t1.start()
        #except:
        #   print ("Error: unable to start thread")
        
        self.root.switch_to(self.root.screens[windows.mainWindow.value])
        self.currentFrame = windows.mainWindow.name

    # checking the ip address
    def checkIP(self, text):

        st = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        try:
            st.connect((text, 1))
            IP = st.getsockname()[0]
            return True
        
        except:
            return False

# entry point 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    UAVApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `switch_to()` method of `ScreenManager`. Not well documented, but this method removes the old `Screen` when it switches to the new `Screen`. So the number of `Screens` in the `screens` list gets reduced causing the index error.

A fix is to use the `current` property of `ScreenManager` rather than `switch_to()`. Try replacing:

```
self.root.switch_to(self.root.screens[windows.mainWindow.value])
```

with:

```
self.root.current = "Main"
```

And your texture update is happening on the main thread because you are calling the `frame_capture()` method by using `Clock.schedule_interval()`, which puts it on the main thread.